# Is there a way to implement dynamic factory pattern in c++?

Tags: c++, reflection, factory, factory-pattern

> The DYNAMIC FACTORY pattern describes how to create a factory that
>   allows the creation of unanticipated products derived from the same
>   abstraction by storing the information about their concrete type in
>   external metadata

from : http://www.wirfs-brock.com/PDFs/TheDynamicFactoryPattern.pdf

Comment: And what's the problem with such implementing it in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...

Look at the [Factories](https://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/page_factories.html) classes in the [Qtilities](https://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/index.html) Qt library.

@TonyD regarding

> We can change the behavior of an application by just changing its configuration information.

It is 100% possible if you interpret the sentence in another way. What I read and understand is you change a configuration file (xml in the doc) that gets loaded to change the behaviour of the application. So perhaps your application has 2 loggers, one to file and one to a GUI. So the config file can be edited to choose one or both to be used. Thus no change of the application but the behaviour is changed. The requirement is that anything that you can configure in the file is available in the code, so to say log using network will not work since it is not implemented.

> New product types should be easily added without requiring neither a new factory class nor modifying any existing one.

Yes that sounds a bit impossible. I will accept the ability to add ones without having to change the original application. Thus one should be able to add using plugins or another method and leave the application/factory/existing classes in tact and unchanged.

All of the above is supported by the example provided. Although Qtilities is a Qt library, the factories are not Qt specific.

Comment: I don't see the config thing cutting it: consider the PDF's *"Controlled Evolution: users can create new types of products conforming to the product interface, but providing unanticipated behavior or features."*.  Everything that can be configured was anticipated, but then obviously the paper's preparedness to use a set of metadata implies a combinatorial set of anticipated needs too - the paper's basically crap IMHO.

Comment: @TonyD I agree, before the post I quickly scanned the paper and after the post revisited a few things. If such things were possible, for example _but providing unanticipated behavior or features_ I think software developers will become obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF says:

> Configurability
>   . We can change the behavior of an application by just changing its configuration 
>   information.  This can be done ***without the need to change any source code*** (just change the descriptive information about the type in the metadata repository) or to restart the application (if caching is not used – if caching is used the cache will need to be flushed).

It is not possible to introduce new types to a running C++ program without modifying source code.  At the very least, you'd need to write a shared library containing a factory to generate instances of the new type: but doing so is expressly rules out by the PDF:

> Extensibility / Evolvability
>   . New product types should be easily 
>   added without ***requiring neither a 
>   new factory class nor modifying 
>   any existing one***.

This is not practical in C++.

Still, the *functionality* can be achieved by using metadata to guide some code writing function, then invoking the compiler (whether as a subprocess or a library) to create a shared library.  This is pretty much what the languages mentioned in the PDF are doing when they use reflection and metadata to ask the virtual machine to create new class instances: it's just more normal in those language environments to need bits of the compiler/interpreter hanging around in memory, so it doesn't seem such a big step.